# Erro de sintaxe no SELECT MAX

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema de sintaxe no meu código sql dentro do código php, preciso saber qual o vídeo tem o maior id no banco de dados para salvar ele em uma pasta separada com o mesmo numero do id, para que o caminho fique salvo no banco.
O erro que acontece é:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�deo)FROM video' at line 1**

```
<?php 
include "Conection.php";
include "select.php";
$nome = $_POST['nome_video'];
$genero = $_POST['genero'];
$comando = "SELECT MAX(id_vídeo)FROM video;";
$select = mysqli_query($con,$comando);
if (!$select){
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}
$dado = mysqli_fetch_array($select); 
$max_id = $dado['id_vídeo'];
$new_id = $max_id + 1;
$a = "C:/Users/ian/Desktop/UploadTeste/".$new_id;
print $a;
$query = "INSERT INTO video (CPF,nome_vídeo,genero,caminho) VALUES ('$cpf_cookie','$nome','$genero','$a');";
$insert = mysqli_query($con,$query);
mysqli_close($con);
if($insert== true){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('upload realizado com sucesso!');window.location.href='MinhasProducoes.php'</script>";
}
else{
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível fazer o upload desse vídeo');window.location.href='##EnviarProdução.php'</script>";
}
$destino = 'C:/Users/Ian/Desktop/UploadTeste/' . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['$new_id'];

move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  );
```

Comment: De uma olhada nos parênteses estao colados no from.

Comment: $comando = "SELECT MAX(id_vídeo)FROM video;"; Bom, não precisa do ";" dentro do select, e video tem mesmo acento? (acho que isso pode ser o erro).

Comment: Sim, tem mesmo acento e não consigo dar um alter table, por que é chave primaria :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema é a codificação do acento em **id_video**:

```
SELECT MAX(id_vídeo)FROM video;
```

Muito provável que seu arquivo esteja com uma **codificação diferente do que o cliente mysql espera**

Exemplo por linha de comando:

```
SELECT MAX(id_vídeo) FROM video;
+------------+
| MAX(vídeo) |
+------------+
|       NULL |
+------------+
```

Agora o mesmo exemplo, só que o caractere copiado da sua pergunta (simulando um caractere inválido:

```
SELECT MAX(id_v�deo)FROM video;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?deo)FROM a' at line 1
```

(Observe que o erro é o mesmo, mostrando a exata posição do caractere inválido, é só um exemplo, posso ter usado codificações diferentes aqui que resultam no mesmo problema)

**Para corrigir:**

- Veja em qual codificação está seu arquivo, utilize [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php) para fazer seu cliente mysql (php/pdo) usar a mesma codificação que seu arquivo
- Ou salve seu arquivo na mesma codificação do cliente mysql (php/pdo)

**Sugestões**:

- Em vez de brigar com os acentos em mysql (mesmo que o MySQL tenha suporte para isso), utilize colunas com nomes de a-z e _, assim você não se preocupa com codificações diferentes.
- Se você tiver problemas em alterar chaves primárias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703126/how-do-i-rename-a-primary-key-column-in-mysql
  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71353/how-to-change-mysql-table-auto-increment-primary-key
- Separe as colunas do SELECT com espaço antes de `FROM`, o MySQL apenas entendeu a separação dos Tokens nas Query por causa do parênteses em `MAX(id_vídeo)FROM`